# Sabre API Request EnhancedAirBooking issue

Tags: api, sabre

while making request for EnhancedAirBooking for  getting the error response **INVALID BOARD POINT**

But it works fine for other flightNumber and MarketingAirLineCode. 
Sample RequestBody for which getting the above error response:

```
   <soap_env:Body>
  <EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3" version="3.0.0" HaltOnError="true">
     <OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NN" />
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
           <FlightSegment FlightNumber="572" DepartureDateTime="2018-07-15T22:05:00" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" ResBookDesigCode="K">
              <DestinationLocation LocationCode="JNB" />
              <Equipment AirEquipType="74H" />
              <MarketingAirline Code="SA" FlightNumber="7572" />
              <MarriageGrp Ind="false" />
              <OperatingAirline Code="LH" />
              <OriginLocation LocationCode="FRA" />
           </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="9" WaitInterval="9000" />
     </OTA_AirBookRQ>
     <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
           <OptionalQualifiers>
              <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="CHF">
                 <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
              </PricingQualifiers>
           </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
     </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
  </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to provide Marketing Carrier and Marketing Carrier Flightnumber. What leads to confusion here, is that you passed the operating flight number in the node where the marketing carrier flight number is expected. If you want to pass the "572" it should be done in the operating carrier part, but its not required to have it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you are sending the request with a different flight number. You should be sending FlightNumber="7572" in the FlightSegment node, not "572".

Comment: Thanks, now it does not raise error in this case. But I am little confused.Cause in **FlightSegment** node FlightNumber=572 is the operating_flight_code of the same flight. FlightNumber="7572"  is the marketing_flight_code.